# Rails 3 Action Mailer: Possible to send email to self from User's email (for 'Contact Us' form)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to make a mailer for a contact us form. The email would be `:from` user@email.com and be `:to` my@email.com . Is this possible to do over SMTP in development? Does ActionMailer actually send the email from the users email account or is it just a fake email? The reason I want to use user@email.com as the sender is because I want it to be easy for me to just reply to that email directly.

I'm trying to use localhost and I'm receiving an error: `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):` I think it is because I haven't set up the settings properly. Is it required to have a username/password on an actual gmail account for this email to be sent?

This is my settings right now (I didn't have any username/password, so could this be the source of my error?):

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => '127.0.0.1',
  :port                 => 25
}
```

controller:

```
def email
  ContactMailer.contact_form(params).deliver
end
```

mailer:

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :to => "my@email.com"

  def contact_form(sender)
    @sender = sender
    mail(:from => sender[:email], :subject => "Question from #{sender[:company] ?     sender[:company] : "" } 
                                              - Contact Us")
  end
end
```

views/contact_mailer/contact_mailer.text.erb:

```
We have been contacted by <%= @sender[:email] %>
```

FIXED

I added this line to my initializer:

`ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail`

Comment: You don't run SMTP server in local machine (127.0.0.1). You either need to set it up (which is kinda complicated and is not really that necessary in development) or configure development environment to use external SMTP server (i.e. Gmail) like in production

Comment: But how will I know if my emails actually send if I use different settings?

Comment: Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-mailer and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html. You also need external service called SMTP server, address (address, port, credentials, and whatever it wants) of which you need to add to configuration. It's the same as with database - you require it using ActiveRecord, but Rails don't set it up for you, so if you use ActionMailer and you want to deliver emails, you need to set it up (search for smtp servers for your platform) or use external service like Gmail.

Comment: Error you got (Connection refused) simply indicates that ActionMailer cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:25 to send email through it.

Comment: Also: fields "from" and "to" are used in email content only, but you can use different credentials when connecting to SMTP server (if it allow you to change/fake them in content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Letter Opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) for you development.

Answer (score 0):

@Edmund, I'm curious, when you say "FIXED" does that mean you fixed this problem by adding that line to your initializer? If so mind clarifying which file exactly?

My understanding [per this paid tutorial](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) is that you shouldn't need to set up any SMTP settings because you only need those if you're sending email out of your own account (i.e., SMTP allows ActionMailer to go into your account and send email on your behalf).

I will say though that this presents an odd assumption... that ActionMailer somehow is able to send email from someone else's account without knowing anything about their SMTP settings.

Anyways, this is a weird part answer, because that's what the tutorial has taught me, but I can't actually get it to work, so I'd also be curious to see what worked for you.